# Error importing back a postgres db after dumping

Tags: postgresql

I dumped my postgres db using pgAdmin in plain format because I wanted to search for some text on it. After doing the search, I decided to import the db back from the sql query window but I get this error

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "330"
LINE 48882: 330 643 644 1 2012-01-11 16:04:20.468 2012-01-17 22:33:23.99...`

This is the part that gives the error. I know I didn't modify anything here. It is what it dumped for me

```
COPY account_account (id, parent_left, parent_right, create_uid, create_date, write_date, write_uid, code, reconcile, currency_id, user_type, active, name, level, company_id, shortcut, note, parent_id, currency_mode, type) FROM stdin;
330 643 644 1   2012-01-11 16:04:20.468 2012-01-17 22:33:23.993 1   40300010    f   \N  8   t   Rent Income 5   1   \N  \N  329 current other
55  89  94  1   2012-01-05 23:50:08.524 2012-01-10 12:32:51.934 1   12000000    f   \N  18  t   Long Term Investments   3   1   \N  \N  24  current view
```

Here is the code that creates the table

```
CREATE TABLE account_account (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    parent_left integer,
    parent_right integer,
    create_uid integer,
    create_date timestamp without time zone,
    write_date timestamp without time zone,
    write_uid integer,
    code character varying(64) NOT NULL,
    reconcile boolean,
    currency_id integer,
    user_type integer NOT NULL,
    active boolean,
    name character varying(128) NOT NULL,
    level integer,
    company_id integer NOT NULL,
    shortcut character varying(12),
    note text,
    parent_id integer,
    currency_mode character varying(16) NOT NULL,
    type character varying(16) NOT NULL
);
```

I am so confused here. Please what could be the problem

Comment: I think the empy lines are the problem (you may not have an empty line after the COPY statement and also not between each "data line"). Is it possible your editor messed up the line endings?

Comment: Actually there are no line. I am the one that put the <br> tags that made those lines appear. I have removed them now

Comment: Have you previous COPY statement ended with `\.`?

Comment: @Jan Marek I don't have. That is first COPY statement in the sql query

Comment: May be you can dump the data as insert sql instead, just have a try.

Comment: @yankitwizzy Because it is line 48882 - have you ended previous statement correctly? (By semicolon, for example)? Or is there a good number of parameters on this line?

Comment: @JanMarek Like I told you, it was pgAdmin that dumped the db for me. I did not do anything on that line so why would it now be seeing it as an error?

Comment: @yankitwizzy I'm sorry, but I'm trying to help you :-). It is possible, that editor, in which you searched a text, changed for example tabs to spaces?

Comment: @JanMarek I used Notepad++ to do the search. Does it change text like that?

Comment: @yankitwizzy According to [this question on stackoveflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/notepad-tabs-to-spaces) it can did it. Can you check, if there are a tabs between values?

Comment: @JanMarek Yeah there are tabs between values. I just checked now

Comment: @yankitwizzy Hmmm... Can you try to import this file via `psql -h machine.with.postgresql -U username -f name.of.dumped.file name_of_database` command? Will it produce the same error?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and Postgres 8.3. It doesn't have that command

Comment: @yankitwizzy Are you sure? Can you explore Postgresql installation directory, if there is not a psql binary? I don't know Postgres under Windows, but on Linux, there is `psql` utility standard part of postgresql client instalation... My opinion is, that there is someone changing a tabs to spaces, maybe internet browser? Otherwise I have no idea, where is problem, I'm sorry.

Comment: @yankitwizzy how was this installed? was it installed using the pg installer? were just the binaries unzipped?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot `COPY FROM stdin` with pgAdmin (no `stdin` available in the query window), but you can easily restore the dump with [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html)

```
psql <database> -h <host> -p <port> -f <dump-file>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok thanks. The thing is that I don't have psql in my postgres installation. Is there a way I can install it as an addon to the existing postgres installation

Comment: Sure, what OS are you running on? On Debian it's as simple as `apt-get install postgresql-client-9.1` to install the current version of PostgreSQL client programs including `psql`.

Comment: I am running Windows 7 64 bits

Comment: Simple try to search psql.exe, you will have it in the directory, where is Postgres installed in, in the 'bin' subdirectory. Then try to use it for importing dump, as I or tscho wrote. I've tried to download installation package for Win 64bit and there was psql.exe binary.

Comment: please note, that on PostgreSQL 9.3 on Windows you should use `psql.exe -h <host> -p <port> -f <file> db_name user_name` so options first, than db_name and user name